# How can i initialize List of reference type with same elements that will use same constructor?

Tags: c#, list, initialization

I want to initialize `List<File>` with exact size and all elements should be created using constructor with parameters.

Here's File class:

```
public class File
{
    public int Value;
    public File(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

I cannot change this class.

I tried using `Files = new List<File>(new File[filesCount])` but this way each element is null but atleast i got the size of List right. Then i used `Files.Foreach(x => x = new File(0))` and as it was expected it didn't work as we can't change object that we got while iterating.

At the end of the day i want to have a `List<File>` where all items are `Files` and have `Value` of 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the System.Linq `Enumerable` class:

```
var Files = Enumerable.Repeat(new File(0), filesCount).ToList();
```

Comment: It worked thanks. I'll mark as correct as soon as i'll be able to